# flask server exit without any message due to pandas crash

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have no idea why the server crashed without any error information after a http request.

How to enable it to show exceptions, thanks

web.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=APP_CFG["server_port"])
# vim: tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```

console log

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
218.174.206.147 - - [17/Apr/2015 09:14:36] "GET /materials?table_name=1&measure=actual%2Cupper_end_of_central_tendency HTTP/1.1" 200 -
218.174.206.147 - - [17/Apr/2015 09:14:37] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
218.174.206.147 - - [17/Apr/2015 09:14:37] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

pip package versions

```
argh (0.26.1)
command-not-found (0.3)
Flask (0.10.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
language-selector (0.1)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
numpy (1.9.1)
pandas (0.15.2)
pathtools (0.1.2)
pip (6.0.8)
pycurl (7.19.3)
pygobject (3.12.0)
python-apt (0.9.3.5)
python-dateutil (2.4.0)
pytz (2014.10)
PyYAML (3.11)
setuptools (12.1)
six (1.9.0)
ufw (0.34-rc-0ubuntu2)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
watchdog (0.8.3)
Werkzeug (0.10.1)
```

I found the buggy section is that Pandas bug.

If I tried to invoke `to_json()` on a empty dataframe.

The process will exit without any message.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, schedule_id, measures]
Index: []
(Pdb) rr.to_json()
```

Comment: What is the response code in the client side? Unless it is 500 or timedout you cannot be sure that server "crashed".

Comment: I can't really see where it crashes. 
Is your problem in
 * Restarting with stat ?

Comment: "crashed" ? how did you confirm?

Comment: had crash in django, reverted back to `0.15.2` for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in 0.16.0, fixed in master (will be released in 0.16.1, at the end of april). See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9805)